# Controlling characters that dictate sorting in SQL Server Order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

So I have this code:

```
select *
from Names
where organization like 'Bank of America%'
order by organization
```

**And I have values that look like and would ideally sort like this:**

Bank of America

Bank of America, Alabama

Bank of America, NA

Bank of America N A

Bank of America South Carolina

**But when I run the code, it sorts like this, saying spaces are before commas:**

Bank of America

Bank of America N A

Bank of America South Carolina

Bank of America, Alabama

Bank of America, NA

How can I get this regular expression: [^a-z A-Z0-9] that will strip out all punctuation into the order by clause so that it will only take those characters into consideration when sorting?

Comment: Regex replacement doesn't exist in SQL Server, you would have to use a CLR function. Seems like you'd be better off sorting the data in your presentation layer.

Comment: Ok so there is no way to do it easily then. Unfortunately I cant really do it on presentation because I am only displaying 20 of 1000s of records at a time, and I need to be displaying based on the entire list sorted. Unless I sorted the entire list when returned, but that would presumably be slower

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a comma that throws you off you could try this. Also if there are a few characters you could nest the replace.

```
select *
from Names
where organization like 'Bank of America%'
order by replace(organization,',','')
```